# Can't see results in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have thise segment of C# code:

```
private void btn_getPixels_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add("Pixel             Color");
    try
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Color c;

        for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {
                c = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                listBox1.Items.Add(i + "," + j + "   " + c.Name);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("SUCESSFULLY DONE");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that after external loop is done,I dont see any result in listBox1.

Any idea how to fix this problema?

Comment: You don't get an Exception? And it is going through the loop? It doesn't somehow think that Width and/or Height == 0 and just stops? Have you debugged through it?

Comment: try adding a messagebox which prints out the contents of c before you add it to the listbox, to check if it has a value

Comment: Wrong form object reference, typically.  Add this.Show() to see the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code works successfully (I checked). It seems because of `img.Width` or `img.Height` are large values and your program are still working (so that you can not see an result). try this loop and see result:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont have any problems with your code:
[image]

Of course, mb you have to change width and height for testing.